# VueJS no me muestra la fecha la hacer click

Tags: html5, vue.js, botón, input-type

¿Alguien sabe cómo usar `vue.js` para mostrar fechas? Tengo este ejemplo pero no me muestra la fecha la hacer click.

Código Vue.js y HTML:

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data() {
            return {
                Date: {day:''},
                masDate: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
            }
        },
    })

</script>

<div id="#app">
    <div class="container text-center   justify-content-center container-user">
        <!-- <h1>slecciona la fecha {{date.day}}</h1> -->
        <form @submit.prevent="getUpdates">
            <input type="datetime-local" v-model="date-day" :max="masDate" >
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">slecciona</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has visto la documentación de VueJS? Mira este fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue/ Tu primer error está en usar `id="#app"` cuando ese signo de `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Debes establecer una variable y luego asignarla con el `v-model`.

Por lo que una solución sería asignar la variable que tienes declarada en el `v-model="date-day"` entiendo que debe ser un error de sintaxis así que deberías corregirlo haciendo lo siguiente:

```
<input type="datetime-local" v-model="masDate" :max="masDate" >
```